# Too many questions for a form in MS access

Tags: ms-access

I'm creating a form in Microsoft Access to enter data from a questionnaire. The problem is that the page is not big enough to fit my questions and the questions at the end stack up on top of eachother at the bottom of the page.

I have extended the page as much as possible. Can it be extended further? Or can I create two pages for each post in MS Access?

Many thanks for advice!

Malin

Comment: No, it cannot be extended further. My guess is you have a bad db structure. Is each question a field? You could maybe make use of a tab control and organize questions across multiple pages of tab control.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information, but another approach is to treat the forms like pages.  page 1 is form 1 with x questions.  At the bottom of page 1 is a button that says go to page 2.  the button closes page 1 and opens page 2 which is form 2 and so on.  Here is a link to a youtube video that shows adding a button that closes the current form and opens another form: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbIk6pc8Inc